# RecyclerView - how to set custom scroll interpolator

Tags: android-recyclerview, scroll, interpolation

### I create RecyclerView programmatically:

---

```
private fun initRecyclerView() {
    RecycleView(context).apply {
        setHasFixedSize(true)
        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context, VERTICAL, true)
        adapter = SlotAdapter().apply { submitList(cells) }
    }
    addView(slot)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

RecycleView . **smoothScrollBy**(dx: Int, dy: Int, interpolator: Interpolator, duration: Int)

```
fun startSpinning() {
    val bottom = slot.bottom
    val interpolator = PathInterpolatorCompat.create(0.40f, 0.55f, 0.15f, 0.75f)
    slot.smoothScrollBy(0, -bottom.dp, interpolator, 5000)
}
```

Dp

```
val Int.dp: Int
get() = (this * Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.density + 0.5f).toInt()
```

Interpolator

To create a ***custom interpolator*** use { PathInterpolatorCompat.create } with values Bezier Curve - http://www.css3beziercurve.net/